# Bound on path length of a stock price

Tags: equities, returns, algorithmic-trading, geometric-brownian

Consider a time series $(S_i)$ representing a stock price (say close prices of one minute candles). Let $\Delta$ be a quantization step (could be the price step in the strike prices of the corresponding options) and let $$K \triangleq \sup_j \cfrac{ \left ( \sum_{j=1}^{r}  \lfloor \lvert S_{i_j}-S_{i_{j-1}}\rvert / \Delta \rfloor \right )} {(R / \Delta)}.$$ Here, the indices $i_j$ come from the index set $(i_0,i_2,...,i_k)$ such that $1 \leq i_0 < i_1 < ... < i_k \leq n$ assuming there were $n$ close prices each day. To evaluate $K$, we just need the supremum of this expression for all possible values of $j$ given the constraints on the indices as shown above. I tried to formulate the numerator based on the [standard expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Formula_for_a_smooth_curve) from analysis for the path length of a function with the difference of having quantized the absolute difference by $\Delta$.

Basically I have tried to define a measure $K$ that measures the discretized path length of the stock price normalized by the range $R$ of the stock price which is the difference between the max and min bounds of that stock price series during that day.

Is it possible for us to have $K > 10$ (ten is arbitrary here but it can be any big number) consistently every day for years together? Put in other words, can the stock move between a limited price range each day but cross strike prices a lot of times throughout the day consistently for years together? If not, what is the constraint due to which it cannot do that?

Comment: Have you tried looking at historical time series of prices of some stocks to test whether they bounce as you describe? Also, do dividends matter?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote but yes ... I am basing this question on historical data for some asset. Ten is admittedly a big number but nevertheless I think this question deserves a proper answer. Whoever downvoted this, please let me know the reason so that I know the reason for it, and might even take down the question if that reason is valid.

Comment: not sure I understand your notation, what does $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ means? if it is the positive part, the absolute value being positive already, I do not get it.
I do not understand the sup over $j$ neither since it is in the sum sign: this is a dummy variable, no?

Comment: The symbol $\lfloor.\rfloor$ is the floor function ($\lfloor 1.1 \rfloor =1$, $\lfloor 0.1 \rfloor =0$ and $\lfloor -0.9 \rfloor = -1$ etc.) ie it is the highest integer closest to its value but lesser than that value. As regards to the $\sup$ over all $j$, I have added more information in the post. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: unfortunately it is not really better, you probably want to get the supremum over all the possible partition in $k+1$ intervals of $n$ integers? in such a case you need to define the set of all the partitions, such that it is made of operators allowing to write properly your sum. I think that your difficulties come essentially from the fact that your problem is ill-posed at this stage.

Comment: So you opine that it is ill-posed due to mathematical difficulty in handling it? The term $\lfloor \lvert S_{i_j}-S_{i_{j-1}}\rvert / \Delta \rfloor$ evaluates the absolute difference between prices at different points in time, and quantizes it by $\Delta$. So the entire expression in the numerator is trying to fit as many "blocks" of $\Delta$ as possible in this sequence, and $K$ is the same thing normalized by the range of the prices throughout the day expressed as a fraction of $\Delta$.

Comment: So can we have too many blocks of $\Delta$ moves in the stock price relative to the range of the day or is there something that prevents it from exceeding certain limit? That is the question that I tried to express mathematically. I feel that the math is secondary. The idea needs to be clear. Expressions can be changed (or if you prefer to say "posed better", I am ok with that too) but the primary thing is to ensure if the question makes sense qualitatively. Do you have any idea if the "length" of the stock price can be too many $\Delta$s? You can define length that you think makes more sense.

Comment: I think the question is well-posed. It is conceivable (even for a real stock price from a historical time series) that $|S_{t_j}-S_{t_{j-1}}|/\Delta$ exceeds any given limit for every $j\,.$ Therefore their average, $K$ exceeds that limit. Whether we find such a time series is of course another question. Side note: we usually model $S_t$ with Brownian motion which has infinite variation which is nothing else than the limit of $K$ for $\Delta\to 0\,.$

Comment: Quoting from Emanuel Derman's book "The Volatility Smile", he says "If you want to value something, do it by comparing it to something else whose price you already know." Simplest example is the put-call parity. I suppose options are also priced based on a replicating portfolio where the hedge ratio is dynamically changed to replicate the payoff of the option contract. The reason I posed this question was to understand if some fairly simple trading scheme (possibly involving other instruments) can result in an arbitrage. In that case, $K$ will have to be bounded or else EMH would be violated.